# Posting to web forms using dynamic inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web forms app which has a piece of jquery that generates a set of inputs, sets the names and ID's correctly to the web forms type names and ID's.

Yet when i post the form back to the server, i cannot find any of those controls with `FindControl`, though i am able find the original control that is part of the form that the other inputs are `clone`d from.

I have attempted to use `FindControl` and used a Recursive version of `FindControl` that i have created, but nothing can be found. Do i have to go down the `Request.Form` route, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont find the `controls` generated by `jQuery` on server side as server controls have their `ViewState` which asp.net uses on post back. You can use a hidden field to assign the values of your dnymically generaterd code to it and get them from this hidden field on server side code. You will need to make hidden field `runat="server"`

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnjQueryGeneratedControls" runat="server" />
```

*OR*

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnjQueryGeneratedControls" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find the control is because you generate them on the client side and not from the server side. using runat=server

you can:

1. call ajax method to send the data from the imputs to the server
2. Create the dynamic inputs from your server side, using repeater of listview